# Why does my object get overwritten in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, overwrite

Im trying to create a grid of pointers to objects.

To do so, I made two classes, the first one is called Pixel, stores the pixel's info, and the second one is the Grid class, which constructor creates a matrix of pointers directed to a Pixel object.

The problem comes when I instantiate a Pixel object and a Grid object, the pixel object gets overwritten.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Pixel{
    private:
        char cel_type;
    public:
        Pixel(void){cel_type = 'O';};
        Pixel(char _type){cel_type = _type;};
        char getType(){return cel_type;}
        ~Pixel(){};
};

class Grid{
    private:
        int rows, cols;
        Pixel  g[0][0], *p[0][0];
    public:
        Grid(int, int); //create the grid

};

Grid::Grid(int M, int N){
    Pixel p0('C'), *pt; 
    rows = M;
    cols = N;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            g[i][j] = p0; // THE PROBLEM ?
            p[i][j] = &p0;

        };
    };
    
};

int main(){
    int M = 3, N = 4;
    Pixel p1('A'), p2('B');
    std::cout<<"Before: "<<p1.getType()<<p2.getType()<<std::endl;
    Grid g(M,N);
    std::cout<<"After: "<<p1.getType()<<p2.getType()<<std::endl;
    
};
```

This should print:

- Before: AB
- After: AB

But instead, it gives:

- Before: AB
- After: C

Why are p1 and p2 getting overwritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Grid constructor, p0 is a local variable. It disappears when the constructor ends. &p0 is the address of a local variable. It points to random rubbish when the constructor ends. So whatever you stored into p is rubbish pointers.

But it's worse. You declared g and p to be arrays of size 0. (Why the heck is your compiler even allowing that?) So when you initialise Grid, it stores lots of Pixels and pointers heaven knows where.